# What would be the right interpretation of this IIR block diagram?

Tags: infinite-impulse-response

[image: Left part IIR block diagram]

Will this block diagram always produce on the top-right arrow the following difference equation?
$y[n]=x[n]+y[n-1]*(-2r)+y[n-2]*(-r^{2})$

Or by the contrary, it can produce also the following?

$y[n]=(x[n]+y[n-1]*(-2r)+y[n-2]*(-r^{2})) + (y[n-3]*(-2*r)+y[n-4]*(-r^{2})) + (y[n-5]*(-2*r)+y[n-6]*(-r^{2})) + ...$

And so on and so on, up to predefined limit of recursion level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the upper equation. It is indeed a recursive filter but the recursion is already build into the difference equation through $y[n-1]$ and $y[n-2]$